# Flex Box Behavior

Tags: html, css

I cannot understand WHY I am not getting this:

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 3px solid green;
}

.cg-panel {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cg-panel .content {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cg-panel">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I, for the life of me, cannot understand why the `content` panel does not vertically stretch the entire container.  What is the purpose of "flex:1" if it isn't going to work?  Am I not reading the documentation correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing in your CSS that is expanding the height of `.cg-panel` to fit its parent `.container`.

Adding `height: 100%;` to `.cg-panel` fixes this:

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 3px solid green;
}

.cg-panel {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%; /* add this */
}

.cg-panel .content {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cg-panel">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Such a rookie mistake.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Elcid_91 No problem, glad that fixed it!